# Will I be fired?

Tags: work-environment

I got suspended for having an altercation with a co-worker. We were face to face and it was due to her not cleaning a patients room whom is related to me. Me and her are custodian workers at a hospital. I was upset on how dirty her area was and to find that our supervisors never tell her nothing but only wanna be telling me to make sure I’m following up with the job but yet her area she’s assigned is filthy and mines isn’t. She has 2 1/2 months working with us. I regret stepping up to her face although she’s the one that suggested to do so. I was having a bad day and unleashed my stress towards that situation. I didn’t curse at her nor hit her, we were just up close at each other’s face . They suspended me two days after and told me I would get called once a decisions had been made whether I’m staying or getting fired.

I have union and my area manager that’s taking care of this situation doesn’t like me at all. She writes me up for any little thing. She wrote me up for saying “stupid shit” while talking about things outside of work but she never writes up other employees for cursing loud in the hallways. she also discriminated me for wearing a skeleton cardigan to work calling it unprofessional as a hospital housekeeper and for having pink highlights at the tip of my hair. note that the company policy says nothing about colored hair or designed sweaters. I currently have two write ups which are for petty reasons for example saying stupid shit, and for telling a coworker to stop speaking about my work business to every other employee. Everytime she sees me she’s looking to see if I have the wrong shoes on or if I’m taking scrubs or not while others wear jeans and gets away with it. There’s always something about me that sets her off. So with this happening I feel like she’s going to terminate me.

But I have union so I’m not sure if they can help me with this type of situation.

Comment: Honestly, you sound like you have a problem taking responsibility for your own actions. What your coworkers do is immaterial. If you think you're being unfairly singled out you should file a grievance with your union representative. We have no way to know whether or not you'll be fired.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee the union will assist you. Especially if you've been having problems with other employees. But if you pay your union dues, you certainly should go to them in any case for assistance. In the future, it would be best to dispute any write-ups as they occur, so if you do misstep, as you have here, there is not a "history" of bad performance.

Comment: Nobody here can tell you whether you're going to be fired. Please consider editing your question to something that people here can reasonably answer.

Comment: You should have involved the Union when you were being picked on by the manager compared to the others **before** it got this far...

Comment: Which country, please? My guess is Spain?

Answer (score 7):

We really can't tell you if you're going to fired. They have made it clear that they are considering it. They have made it clear that once a decision has been made they will contact you. At this point we can't say any more than they are probably telling the truth and considering.

But seeing as you're afraid of being fired I really think you should reflect on your behavior and try to better yourself. You may be great at your job, but from the way you describe things you are having a lot of issues with boundaries at work.

### The current incident

You mention "stepping up to her face" and if this is to be understood in the literal sense, then that is really crossing a line. You should never treat co-workers that way and they are right to take action here.

### Your language

You mention being written up for your language when others are not. While this in itself sounds unfair, I would like to point out that if you repeatedly have a hard time understanding expected boundaries, then breaking then sometimes a small overstep is all it takes to be written up.

### Skeleton Cardigan

You also mention the skeleton cardigan and as I understand it, that's a cardigan with skeletons on it. When working in a hospital that is "unprofessional" at best and unacceptable at worst. I wouldn't expect you to be written up for it, but a comment that you should avoid such imagery in this line of work seems in order.

### Pink Highlights

I'll be honest. I have no idea about the pink highlights, that seems fine by all standards.

### Your attitude towards coworkers

You also mention that you were written up for "telling a coworker to stop speaking about my work business to every other employee", This also seems like crossing a boundary. People on the job talk about each other all the time. If she started talking about your private life. That would be unacceptable. But talking about work stuff is not.

### Conclusion

All in all, while some of these things alone shouldn't cause a write-up, I think this shows a pattern of "drama" and crossing the line. When someone keeps doing that, they will be in danger of termination at pretty much any workplace and I suggest that you look to clean this behavior up. This will serve you much better whether you continue at your current job or find a new one.

Comment: I suspect the issue with "pink highlights" might be slight nitpicking, but it also could be an indication of a huge culture disconnect, between the author and their employee.  The hospital isn't looking for somebody who "rocks the boat", and it seems due to their manager's problems with the authors work attire and hairstyle, there is a serious culture disconnect.  *Sometimes the employee/employer relationship does not work out.*

Answer (score 2):

Your first recourse if you feel threatened (which you should) is to talk to your union. They will know the specifics of your rights and potential actions in your locale and workplace.

You can decide what to do after getting that information.

If you're getting write ups which you feel are unjustified, you should have talked to the Union then. A write up is a permanent record. A personal attack in some cases, don't let those slide, they can bite you further in your career.